# Fibrations that are not fiber bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

I noticed that this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a good answer for it, so here goes. For a course project I am learning about fibre bundles and fibrations, and now I am looking into some examples of both. Now, I would like to find an example of a fibration (either Hurewicz or Serre) that is not a fibre bundle. So far, I have only found the following (incomplete) example:

Let $E := [0, 1]^2 /l$, where $l$  is the line $\{\frac{1}{2}\} \times [0,1]$, and let $B = [0,1]$. Then a fibration $\pi: E \to B$ is not a fibre bundle.

However, I do not know how to define such a fibration $\pi$ explicitly, nor do I know how I would prove that it is a fibration (and whether it is Hurewicz or Serre). Moreover, I would not know how to prove that such a fibration is not a fibre bundle.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone would have any hints regarding the aforementioned problems I have with this example. I would also like to know whether anyone knows any other examples of fibrations that are not fibre bundles. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have a look at Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book, exercises 4.3.8 & 4.3.9.

Answer (score 6):

Let me give you another example with an explicit map:

Consider the subspace $E = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \vert y \vert \leq \vert x \vert \rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. I claim that the projection onto the $x$-axis $$\text{pr} \colon E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto x$$
is not a fiber bundle, but a (Hurewicz-)fibration. First of all, let me draw you a picture of the situation:

[image]

$\bullet$ Why is this not a fiber bundle?

Fiber bundles have homeomorphic fibers. Do you see where this fails?

$\bullet$ Why is this a fibration?

Let me give you a hint and leave the rest to you. I claim that the inclusion $E \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a retraction and that this retraction allows you to steal the homotopy lifting property from the trivial fiber bundle $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (also the projection onto the first component).